# how to stop allowing or prevent minus symbol to enter text box more than once?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc

I have a textbox I have to stop allowing or prevent minus  symbol to enter text box more than once. Can anyone help me on this?

Comment: are you using jquery?

Comment: yes. I have to stop allowing minus symbol to enter textbox more than once. You can give any jquery or javscript code

Answer (score 1):

You *can* stop more than one minus symbol in the textbox by applying a keydown handler and stopping the event if the minus symbol (key 45) is pressed AND there is already a minus sign in the input:

```
$("#MyInputID").keydown(function (e) {   
    if (e.keyCode == 45 && $("#MyInputID").val().indexOf('-') != -1) { 
        event.preventDefault();
    }
});
```

However, it is generally considered bad UX to block input, there might be a better solution for your exact needs - maybe validation, or using a number type input.

But the above should work if you are certain it's what you want to do.

(Also note, this approach won't stop someone *pasting* a value with more than one minus symbol - you'll need validation to deal with that.)

Answer (score 0):

You could use jquery.validation http://jqueryvalidation.org/files/demo/ and add a rule with a regular expression so you can show a message/warning in that particular field to the user saying only one '-' symbol is allowed

Answer (score 0):

Html:

< input type="text" id="textBoxID" onkeyup="clickMe(this)" />

Using javascript:

```
function clickMe(obj)
{
    var textVal = obj.value;
    if (textVal.match(/\-/g).length > 1) {
        alert('you cannot enter - more than once');
    }
}
```

using jquery

```
//Jquery
$('#textBoxID').keyup(function () {
    var textVal = $(this).val();
    if(ele.match(/\-/g).length > 1)
    {
        alert('you cannot enter - more than once');
    }

});
```

Hope this helps